# vba deep copy/clone issue with class object dictionary

Tags: vba, class, excel, dictionary, clone

I have a dictionary in my Main Sub (KEY = string; VALUE = Class Object). The Class Object consists of two dictionaries. As I collect data and check the values stored in the Dictionary Values (Class Object - dictionaries) I noticed that only the last values are getting stored. What I mean is that all the Values in my dictionary in my Main Sub are pointing to the same dictionary reference, hence, all the instances of my Class Objects contain the same data. This means that I need to make a clone of my Class Objects (deep copy?). I have successfully done this before with Class Objects that only stored simple values, but not with dictionaries. I need help cloning my Class Object that contains dictionaries.

MAIN SUB

```
Dim dGroup As New Scripting.Dictionary ' Main Dictionary
'
' loop thru a listbox
  For i = 0 To UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    Gname = UserForm1.ListBox1.List(i) ' get listbox names
' populate temp dictionary
    Set dic = FNC.GET_SESSION_FILE_ELEMENTS(mySesFile, Gname) 
'
' instantiate new Class Object
    Dim NewCol As New cVM_Col
    Call NewCol.INIT(dic) ' pass the dictionary to a 'constructor'
    dGroup.Add Gname, NewCol.CLONE ' add to the MAIN SUB dictionary
'
    Set dic = Nothing ' clear the temp dictionary
  Next i
```

CLASS OBJECT

```
Private dElms As Scripting.Dictionary 
Private dDat As Scripting.Dictionary 
'
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set dElms = New Scripting.Dictionary
  Set dDat = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub
'
Public Sub INIT(inp As Scripting.Dictionary)
  Set dElms = inp
End Sub
'
Public Function CLONE()
  Set CLONE = New cVM_Col
  Set CLONE.dElms = dElms ' <-- THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES
  Set CLONE.dDat = dDat
End Function
```

Normally my CLONE function works when I am only cloning simple data types like String or Long or Double. I've never had to do this with a Dictionary.

Comment: In your constructor `Public Sub INIT(inp As Scripting.Dictionary)`, you're passing the object by reference and not by value, so I guess that's the reason why it keeps on pointing to the last object. Can you please try to add the `ByVal` keyword in front of `inp As Scripting.Dictionary`? Not sure is the problem though, if that doesn't work could you please try to provide a minimal script that works so that we can test?

Comment: In order to get the code to run, I had to remove the "CLONE" feature when adding to the dictionary `dGroup.Add Gname, NewCol`. After adding `ByVal` I still get the same result.

Comment: Alright, can you please share a minimal sample to reproduce the issue, so we can see it via debugger?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks, Matteo. I added some public get/set properties in my Class Object to process the dictionaries. Then in my CLONE function I removed the "set" operator when assigning the dictionaries. I tested it and it works now.

Comment: great, congratulations on solving your own problem. Please add your solution as an answer and don't forget to accept it, so it will be useful to other users having your same issue one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To CLONE the dictionary objects in my CLASS Objects I had to make the following changes:

CLASS OBJECT
(Modified CLONE function)

```
Public Function CLONE()
  Set CLONE = New cVM_Col
  CLONE.Elms = dElms
  CLONE.Dat = dDat
End Function
```

(Added Properties)

```
Public Property Get Elms() As Scripting.Dictionary
  Set Elms = dElms
End Property
Public Property Let Elms(p As Scripting.Dictionary)
  Set dElms = p
End Property
'
Public Property Get Dat() As Scripting.Dictionary
  Set Dat = dDat
End Property
Public Property Let Dat(p As Scripting.Dictionary)
  Set dDat = p
End Property
```